# Preencher campo nulo com primeiro campo anterior não nulo

Tags: postgresql

Boa tarde,

Queria preencher os campos nulos com o primeiro campo anterior não nulo em uma tabela toda. Vocês sabem se tem como fazer?

Como esta a tabela:
[image: Como esta a tabela]

Como deve ficar a tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Os registros estariam sempre na mesma ordem? Se sim você pode atualizar essa tabela utilizando função. Teria como incluir na tua pergunta uma parte dos dados originais? Ficaria mais fácil para eu te mandar um exemplo.

Comment: Bom dia Camilo, os dados sempre serão assim. Os registros nulos logo abaixo sempre receberão o código do produto acima que não seja nulo. No entanto, as vezes ele possui 2 descrições, outras 1, outras 5. Fiz dessa formar para ficar mais fácil para entender. Os dados originais ficariam muito bagunçados para entender.

Answer (score 0):

Como sua tabela sempre manterá essa sequência, pode ser feita uma função que primeiro armazena o código e quando esse campo estiver nulo ele utiliza a variável gravada anteriormente.

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```
do $$
declare
  vRegistros record;
  vCodigo integer;
begin
  --Executa a query e a cada iteração grava a tupla em vRegistros
  for vRegistros in select * from codigo_null order by id loop
    -- Se o campo codigo não for nulo a variável vCodigo receberá o seu valor
    if vRegistros.codigo is not null then
      vCodigo := vRegistros.codigo;
    else
    -- Quando o código for nulo irá atualizar o registro correspondente com o código gravado na iteração anterior
      update codigo_null
      set codigo=vCodigo
      where id=vRegistros.id;
    end if;
  end loop;
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```